# How to pack 2 long values in one single string and get them back

Tags: java, string, hash, encoding

Please help me with some ideas, how could I do this in Java:

Input:

```
long id1 = 123456 (any long value)
long id2 = 4490390904 (any long value)
```

Output:

```
a94dhjfh4990-d49044 (whatever, any string)
```

And then, based on output to get back `id1` and `id2`. So, some kind of enconding, hashing. Not something to obvious (like 123456###4490390904) but also I don't want encryption level...
Just wonder if there is already something I can use provided by Java library (so no 3rd party libraries) or some algorithms (code snippets).

**UPDATE**
Something similar to : https://github.com/peet/hashids.java

Comment: encoding? or hashing? these are different.

Comment: this seems more like an algorithm or calling an api to put said numbers in string then calling algorithm or api to undo.

Comment: With hashing getting the output back is not possible.

Comment: Base64 encoding? Not sure..

Comment: You can simply concatenate the hex value of each long, with a separator. is that too obvious ?

Comment: Without knowing what requirement you are trying to satisfy, this is a really broad question.  Converting to string and then ROT13 would satisfy your criteria just as well as NSA-level encryption schemes.  Is there some sort of business or homework requirement you are trying to satisfy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:
https://github.com/peet/hashids.java

Sorry if I haven't been so precise in my request.

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark, since you are not very precise on the requirements. The following provides 2 functions to *encode* both value in a `String` and to *decode* the `String` into an array of `long`. Each long value is formatted in hexadecimal.

```
public class IdEncoder {

    static final String sep = "-";

    public static String encode(long id1, long id2) {
        return Long.toHexString(id1)+sep+Long.toHexString(id2);
    }

    // Assume the paramater is at the right format.
    // Several exceptions can be thrown. Add exception handling as necessary...
    public static long[] decode(String id) {
        String[] ids = id.split(sep);
        long[] idl = new long[2];
        idl[0] = Long.parseUnsignedLong(ids[0], 16);
        idl[1] = Long.parseUnsignedLong(ids[1], 16);
        return idl;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String ids = encode(123456, 675432187);
        System.out .println(ids);
        long[] idl = decode(ids);
        System.out .println(Arrays.toString(idl));
    }
}
```

prints

> 1e240-284246fb
>   [123456, 675432187]

Answer (score -1):

if it's just any string then you can simply do this:

```
Long a,b;
a=...; b=...;
//coding
String s = a + "#" + b;
//decoding
ab= a.split(s,'#');
System.out.println("a= " + Long.parsLong(ab[0]));
System.out.println("b= " + Long.parsLong(ab[1]));
```

meanwhile you can use SHA-1 explained [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/) to code the middle string

Comment: i dont think thats what he wants. I think he wants to convert the longs into a string as in their value to ASCII

Comment: There is more than Long to String conversion happening, he's looking to encode or hash his string.   Note how his output differs from his input.

Comment: SHA-1 is a one-way algorithm.  He also wants to be able to reverse it and get his original number back, presumably without brute forcing it.